# Is there a way in Excel to have a formula stretch its row extent to include adjacent inserted rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

In Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac OS X, I have several columns of numerical figures and a final row at the bottom that shows a maximum value for each column.  My data set is ordered, such that most recent values are at added at the bottom.  It would be nice if I could just insert a row at the bottom, between the last data row and the formula row, and have the formula row be automatically updated to include the inserted row, however, the inserted row is always omitted when inserted at the bottom.

The closest I've been able to approximate this, is by leaving a blank row between my data and the formula summary row at the bottom, but having the formulas include the blank row in their extent.  The formulas, ignore the blank values in their calculation of `max()`, then when I wish to add another row to the data, I select the blank row, and insert a new blank row above it, where I put the new row of data.

This is a pretty good work around, but I'm still wondering if there is a simpler way to just tell Excel to always extend the formula to include inserted rows that are adjacent to the formula values?

Answer (score 1):

Working from excel 2010 on pc but should be similar

Couple ways.

1. The first is to use a table, highlight the data go to insert>table, should format it with alternating rows.  You can then use formulas like =sum(Table1[myCol]) to sum the entire column
2. Dynamic formulas.  The last row can be returned using a formula like =match(1e300,A:A,1) assuming its numerical and assign it to a named range (lRow).  Use a formula like =sum(A1:indirect("A" & lRow))
3. Or indirect can be right in the named range but then it would only work for 1 column per named range. =indirect("A" & match(1e300,A:A,1)) assigned to a named range (lCellA) and you can use a formula =sum(A1:lCellA)

There would be others but one of those should work.  If you need further explanation on named ranges you can let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Does Mac Excel 2011 include the ability to format areas as Excel Tables?

In Windows Excel, this is on the main tab: Format as Table. This does exactly what you need. You can add a total row automatically at the bottom of the table but I find it easier to manually insert a row above the table and then use the same table sub-totals formula.

For example, I have a sheet that extracts user data from SharePoint. That table has a column labelled "UPN", so I can count the rows in the table with the formula:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, Table6[UPN])
```

(assumes that the table is called "Table6")

You can do other calculations such as:

```
=MIN(Table6[FirstAccessTime])
```

And a sum calculation with:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,Table6[Count])
```